# SandBox paypal = no account optional

Tags: paypal-sandbox, forms

I've been trying to set up a paiement with paypal but I have an issue when testing with the sandbox.
Even though the setting on my account is **Website Payment Preferences/PayPal Account Optional: ON,** I keep having the screen with :

**Create a PayPal account
And pay with your prepaid or credit card**

Or I would expect to have this:

**Don't have a PayPal account?
(Optional) Join PayPal for faster future checkout**

To sum up:

**sandbox = NOK**

```
            <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@yyy.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
                <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
            </form>
```

**live = OK**

```
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@yyy.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
                <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
            </form>
```

Is there another options I didn't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now it works.

I suppose paypal solved this issue (?)